# Reactjs unexpected infinite loop with render

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs

I using React to implemented Include component. It load content from url.
This test works but also produces an unexpected infinite loop with render... why?

```
<script type="text/jsx">
  /** @jsx React.DOM */
  var Include = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
      return {content: 'loading...'};
    },
    render: function() {
      var url = this.props.src;
      $.ajax({
        url: url,
        success: function(data) {
          this.setState({content: data});
        }.bind(this)
      });
      return <div>{this.state.content + new Date().getTime()}</div>;
    }
  });

  var Hello = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return <Include src="hello.txt" />;
    }
  });
  React.renderComponent(
    <Hello />,
    document.getElementById('hello')
  );
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

This is a more reliable Include component.  The differences,

- render should be pure (can't do ajax there)
- getInitialState should be pure
- if the prop is dynamic, e.g. `<Include url={this.state.x} />`, it should update

```js
var Include = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {content: 'loading...'};
  },
  componentDidMount: function(){ 
    this.updateAJAX(this.props.url); 
  },
  componentWillReceiveProps: function(nextProps){
    // see if it actually changed
    if (nextProps.url !== this.props.url) {
      // show loading again
      this.setState(this.getInitialState);

      this.updateAJAX(nextProps.url);
    }
  },
  updateAJAX: function(url){
    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      success: function(data) {
        this.setState({content: data});
      }.bind(this)
    });
  },
  render: function() {
    return <div>{this.state.content}</div>;
  }
});

var Hello = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return <Include src="hello.txt" />;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I realized render is executed a lot of times, so is not better place to my ajax invocation (-_-)'

This way works fine:

```
<script type="text/jsx">
  /** @jsx React.DOM */
  var Include = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
      var url = this.props.src;
      $.ajax({
        url: url,
        success: function(data) {
          this.setState({content: data});
        }.bind(this)
      });
      return {content: 'loading...'};
    },
    render: function() {
      return <div>{this.state.content + new Date().getTime()}</div>;
    }
  });

  var Hello = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return <Include src="hello.txt" />;
    }
  });
  React.renderComponent(
    <Hello />,
    document.getElementById('hello')
  );
</script>
```

Thank you for reading!

Comment: Glad to see you worked out the problem! One small suggestion I'd recommend is to move the ajax call into the componentWillMount method.

The result is the same but using the componentWillMount method results in better seperation of concerns.

I've attached a fiddle so you can what I mean.

P.s - React is awesome

Here's the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NXCyC/50/)

Comment: @user3508122 I believe componentDidMount is correct for this.  It's used in the [official tutorial](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html).  The only reason I can think of, is that componentWillMount is called when using `renderComponentToString` (i.e. server rendering).

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand - Good spot! You are correct - my mistake.